# Why using Guice Provider instead of normal injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Sorry for asking dumb question, but I am quite new to Java and Guice framework. I fail to understand the use of Guice Provider class which provides an instance of any class in compression to the normal injected instance. As far as I understand, it allows you to create multiple instances of a class where as Injected instance is always Singleton. Is it the only difference or is there anything more than this?

i.e.
difference between:

`@Inject
SomeClass someObjcet;`

VS

`@Inject
Provider<SomeClass> provider;
provider.get();`

Comment: Guice injects the instance for you.

Comment: And provider.get() also gives you the instance. So is it just 2 different ways of instantiating an object?

Comment: Do you mean [`@Provides` methods](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods) vs [implementing `Provider<T>`](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProviderBindings)?

Comment: @zapl I mean `Provider<T>` vs `@Inject`. I have edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: so https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InjectingProviders ? Or do you want to create the provider manually instead of injecting it?

Comment: `@Inject
 protected Provider<Scan> scanProvider;`
vs
`@Inject
 protected Scan;`

Answer (score 18):

There are three different reasons you might want to inject a `Provider<T>` instead of just injecting `T` (see [Guice's documentation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InjectingProviders)):

1. Every call to the `get()` method in a `Provider` implementation will (usually) return a *new instance* of the dependency. This would be useful when said instances hold mutable state (otherwise the dependent class, when accessed from multiple threads, could run into concurrency issues).
2. A provider allows for *lazy loading* a dependency which is costly to instantiate. With the provider, the object will *only* be created if and when the `get()` method is called, which is decided by your code.
3. A dependent object from a "wider" scope (often a global singleton) can, through the use of a provider, obtain instances of narrower-scoped objects. For example, it could obtain a request-scoped (or session-scoped) `User` object.

Comment: I can think of one more: 4.) in case of circular dependencies (A gets B injected, B gets A injected) uing providers can solve the parallel creation problem.

Comment: Maybe not as important as the 4 reasons already mentionned, but if you *really* need to inject the Injector itself in a component (you're building some kind of framework, for example), than injecting `Provider<Injector>` is way, way, more faster than injecting `Injector` directly.